# which xcode application for pre filling a database

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am still learning xcode and objective-c. I use to build app for iphone environment only.
However I am in need of realizing an application with an existing prefilled sql database.

For prefilling the database I wouldn't like to use code in the ditributed app, but I would rather prefer to have a separate app for doing that.

The reason is that, the app could only download the updated database, rather than a whole code update .

So, questions are:

1. is this a possible scenario
2. if yes, what kind of application
   should I build in xcode for
   prefilling database ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that you can't have one app that both uses the database and downloads updates. Keeping the database updated without downloading the whole thing is pretty simple.

If you record the creation and modification timestamps of rows in the database on the server and keep track of those same modification timestamps on the device, updating the database works like this:

1. The device determines latest modification timestamp it has for a given table. We'll call it **latestTimestamp**. It sends the **latestTimestamp** to the server.
2. The server compares the **latestTimestamp** to the creation and modification timestamps in the database. The server sends back data based on the comparison result:

   - If the modification timestamp is **earlier** than **latestTimestamp** it doesn't need to send the record, the device already has it;
   - If the modification timestamp is **later** than **latestTimestamp** and the creation timestamp is **earlier** than **latestTimestamp**, it sends the record back noting that it is to be **updated** in the device database;
   - If the modification timestamp is **later** than **latestTimestamp** and the creation timestamp is **later** than **latestTimestamp**, it sends the record back noting that it is to be **added** in the device database.
3. Lastly, the server database needs to keep track of deleted records and a deletion timestamp for every record recorded. If **latestTimestamp** is **later** than the deletion timestamp, it sends back that the record needs to be deleted.

Obviously it gets a bit more complicated when you have a variety of connected tables, but as long as things are sent back in the correct order, it works great.

Use asynchronous data requests (the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library makes it a breeze) and update the data in the background while the user uses the app. If it's essential that the data be updated prior to any interaction with it you can display an activity indicator and have the user wait.

No need at all for a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage you from doing that. No matter it is a pre-filled-database-purpose app, or a normal-purpose app, Apple Review Team would treat them with the same procedure, leaving the developer waiting for weeks before that app is finally available on App Store.

Besides, as far as I know, communication between apps is still strictly limited. If the data you would like to transfer between your main app and your db app is larger than a few lines of, let's say, NSString, it might be technically un-plausible.

Comment: thanks. So the suggestion is to build one app only and doing the work of prefilling directly in the app ? I mean, prefilling at development time in xcode and then distribute app ?

Comment: Yes, either pre-filling during development or including the data in the bundle in an easily-imported format and importing it the first time the app is run. There are pros and cons to both methods.

Comment: just a question come to my mind, how does a newspaper publish fresh news on its apps ? Is this not communication between apps ? What if I exchange info on a, let's say, plist or xml basis, rather than a whole db ?