# pull communication of data from iphone app

Tags: iphone, communication

I developed an application where I can build objects based on a model which is written on a .plist file. The mechanism works very well, data are in form of string, date or int, and the .plist file is really small. 
I was wondering if it's possible to update the model only, which is, at the moment, an update of a plist file.
Before the .plist file I was thinking about a .sqlite database download, but as this post I got strongly discouraged: [which xcode application for pre filling a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482310/which-xcode-application-for-pre-filling-a-database)

So, as main newspapers do, I was thinking about replicate the news update process. In exactly the same way, I don't want this to be a push notification process from the server, but rather an on-demand pull from the iphone.

I am looking for the best way to achieve this. Therefore these are my questions:

1. usual question: can it be done ?
2. is the .plist file a good format candidate for this ?
3. which api, technology... suit best ?
4. can Apple raise any kind of problems about that ? If yes, how can I prevent this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app in the app store now that checks for and downloads a small plist of data every few days. When the app launches, it loads data from its local copy of that file.

I download the file to the documents directory using an NSURLConnection with a delegate so that it loads the data in the background. Then on the connectionDidFinishLoading I check the file and overwrite the old copy if I have no errors.

I have been wanting to add the code described in this blogpost
[That shows how to check for a new version before you download](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/server-communication/how-to-download-a-file-only-if-it-has-been-updated)

I think that Apple would only have a problem if you were downloading so much data that it violated the 1MB/minute rule.

Comment: that seems exactly what I needed. And if it's on the ap store, it's sures that works. Thanks for pointing the code.

Comment: +1. I saw you win the "unsung hero" badge and I felt bad for you so I'm upvoting some of your good-looking 0-score accepted answers. :-)